# How to test if a varible is only letters and not abc1. alsoabout validating emails

Tags: javascript, validation

So I am making a form that asks the user to input their first name and then their last name. Now, if they enter 123 or leave it blank an error will pop up. HOWEVER, if I type zack12, no error will pop up.. any idea how to fix it?

```
var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
        if(fName=="" || !isNaN(fName))
        {
            alert("PLEASE ENTER A FIRST NAME.");
        }
```

Also I have to make sure when they enter their email, it was a @ in it as well as a dot (.). How do I go about that as I am confused. Thanks.

Comment: Use a regular expression to specify the valid format.

Comment: `!isNaN(fName)` --- what this thing is supposed to express?

Comment: If they enter a number as their first name it will provide an error. Its saying if fName is a number

Answer (score 0):

```
function allLetter(inputtxt)  
  {   
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
  if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))  
  {  
  alert('Your name have accepted : you can try another');  
  return true;  
  }  
  else  
  {  
  alert('Please input alphabet characters only');  
  return false;  
  }  
  }
```

from http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/all-letters-field.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateName(){
   var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
   var regxForName= /^[a-zA-Z]+$/; 
     return fName.test(fName);
}

function validateEmail(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

***Test for only letters:***

```
var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
var onlyLetters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
/* /^[A-Za-z]+$/  -> Checks all characters of the string to what's inside [] (including spaces, breaks).
If the first name contains a space, it will not be valid*/
if( onlyLetters.test( fName )===false ){
            alert("PLEASE ENTER A FIRST NAME.");
}
```

Be Aware! Some people first name may contain a Hyphen( - ) for example. The above codes matches the string for only letters (upper and lower case)

**Check email for "@" and "." :**

```
var email = "tester@test.com";
if( email.indexOf("@")<0 || email.indexOf(".")<0 ){
    alert("PLEASE ENTER AN EMAIL ADDRESS.");
}
```